# Trying to Install Java 6

Tags: command-line, java, jdk

I have jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin saved on my "Home" location. When I open the terminal to extract and run the .bin, I get a "No such file or directory" error. I've searched around and can't seem to find anything to fix this. See below for attempted commands:

> root@anon-K52F:~# ./jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin
>
> -bash: ./jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin: No such file or directory
>
> root@anon-K52F:~# chmod +x jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin
>
> chmod: cannot access ‘jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin’: No such file or directory

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3

If anyone has any insight on this, please let me know.

Comment: Try checking with `ls` if you really have that file with that name OR Try entering `j` and then pressing `Tab` twice to see a list of all files and folders starting with `j`. It may be that you are misspelling the filename.

Comment: On second thought, whose `Home` is that (where the file is)? There are different `home`s for root users and normal users.

Answer (score 2):

No such file or directory simply means there is no such file named jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin in your current working directory.

---

BTW, Oracle Java (JDK) 6 / 7 / 8 / 9 is available to install from **WebUpd8-team's** PPA

1. Open a terminal and enter:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   ```
2. To pull down the latest list of packages from the PPA you just added:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. To install JDK 6

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
   ```

But this requires a working internet connection.

Comment: FYI: This method no longer works, see http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html